# How to deselect all the tab in UITabBArController IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a requirement for showing default screen  with deselect all tabs in  TabBarcontroller after that user need to select any Tab bar item is there any option for this in iOS tabBarController

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible. You should write your own implementation of tabbar controller

Comment: How to switch between UIViewController with the UITabBar without TabBarController is there any option for that so I can add the tabBar to the default screen and switch between Viewcontroller from that

Comment: Before approaching this technically I think this has issues even from a UX perceptive. If the user has not selected anything what does he see on the screen?
If there is a valid flow from a UX perspective then you have to align you technical implementation considering that.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any option for this in iOS tabBarController

No. You are *always* in *some* tab. That's what a tab bar controller *is*.

Comment: Yes I know that but client requirement is like that we are coming from another mainviewController to this tabBarController 
is there any other option to use tab bar to switch between viewcontroller

Comment: Perhaps, but that is not what you asked. You asked about the "iOS tabBarController". And I'm telling you that it cannot display _no_ selected tab bar item.